# Guardar una imagen de código de barra generada con extensión barcode en Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

He generado un código de barras con la extensión `barcode.php` con *Javascript* a partir de un numero dado.

El problema es que no logro guardar la imagen, con *PHP* por método *post*.

```
 <div class="form-group col-xs-4">

        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CodigoCompletoActivoR" name="CodigoCompletoActivoR" placeholder="Ingresar Código" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 pull-left">

        <div class="input-group">

        <button class="btn-primary" type="button" id="generar_barcode">Generar código</button>
        
        </div>
    </div>
       
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 pull-right" id="imagen">
        
      </div>

$(document).on("click", "#generar_barcode", function(){
    var data = $("#CodigoCompletoActivoR").val();


 $("#imagen").html('<img src="extensiones/phpbarcode/barcode.php?text='+data+'&size=90&codetype=Code39&print=true"/>');

});
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para enviar la imagen a PHP y también cómo intentas guardarla.

Comment: No tengo código de guardar , por que lo  que he intentado no ha funcionado y no estoy ni cerca de lograrlo, lo que tengo es que se digita el condigo en un input y por un boton y javascript muestro el codigo en pantalla lo proximo que quiero es capturar esa imagen para guardarla en una carpeta

Answer (score 0):

la solución a esto es

require_once "turuta/barcode.php";// llamar el archivo barcode.php
$filepath = turuta/nombredearchi.png; //asignar la ruta y nombre de la imagen del código de barra
$codigo = tucodigodebarra; // asignar el valor del codigo de barra

barcode($filepath, $codigo,'70','horizontal','code128',true,1);// llamar funcion barcode

me funciono perfectamente guardando la imagen en el directorio deseado